# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSSet' with an argument list of type '(array: [NSData?])'

Tags: swift2

Getting this error when updating to swift 2.0:
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSSet' with an argument list of type '(array: [NSData?])'

I already do the searching but still can't fix it.

```
var object:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, result.size.width, result.size.height))
object.image = UIImage(named: "image_default")
let element = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("XKIMAGEVIEW", inManagedObjectContext: CoreDataUtil.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext!) as! XKIMAGEVIEW
element.image = NSSet(array:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(object.image!, 1)])
```

the last line just have the error
seems like NSData couldn't be included in the array

Any idea of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` returns an optional, `NSSet` doesn't accept optionals.
Just unwrap the optional:

```
NSSet(array:[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(object.image!, 1)!])
```

Or, if the image representation could be `nil` use optional bindings

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(object.image!, 1) {
  element.image = NSSet(array:[imageData])
}
```